# How do I add a parameter to an HTTP GET in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass an object in my http get

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/requestoffwork'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
```

I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/requestoffwork',
        someParam: $scope.dt
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
```

Comment: Make it as 'post ' and try it.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to add parameters to the GET query string, you'll need to use the `params` option in the `config` object, like so:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/requestoffwork',
  params : {
    someParam: $scope.dt
  }    
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

Hopefully that helps!